# solve the recurrence relation $a_n = 7a_{n-1} - 16a_{n-2} +12a_{n-3} + n4^n $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recursion, recursive-algorithms

Solve the recurrence relation

$$a_n = 7a_{n-1} - 16a_{n-2} +12a_{n-3} +  n4^n $$

With initial conditions:

$a_0 = −2$

$a_1 = 0$

$a_2 = 5$

I solve the homogenous part like that:

$$a_n - 7a_{n-1} + 16a_{n-2} -12a_{n-3} = 0 $$

$$ p(r) = r^3 -7r^2 + 16r - 12 $$

$$ p(r) = (r-2)^2(r-3) $$

But I am stucked with the non-homogenous part.

For $$ g(n) = 4^n $$ We can use $$ q(r) = A4^n $$ But for $$ g(n) = n4^n $$

What we should do?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, avoid the use of $*$ to denote multiplication. That's a practice in programming, but this is a math forum. Use `x \cdot y` to get $x \cdot y$,`x \times y` to get $x \times y$ or simply use juxtaposition.

Comment: I edited the post!

Answer (score 1):

Given

$$
a_n-7a_{n-1}+16a_{n-2}-12a_{n-3}= n^m 4^n
$$

a particular solution can be obtained by assuming

$$
a^p_n = \left(\sum_{k=0}^{k=m}c_k n^k\right)4^n
$$

for $m=1$ we have $c_0 = -80, c_1 = 16$

for $m=2$ we have $c_0 = 656,c_1=-160,c_2=16$

etc.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n = 7a_{n-1} - 16a_{n-2} +12a_{n-3} +  n4^n$$
Here $g(n)=n4^n$. Try
$$a_n^p=(cn+d)4^n$$
for the particular solution. $c$ and $d$ are constants to be found.

Comment: $$(cn+d)4^n$$ will be written in place of $$a_n$$ and $$(c(n-1)+d)4^(n-1)$$  in place of  $$a_(n-1)$$ and so on? 

Why we are supposing that $$a_n^p=(cn+d)4^n$$?

Comment: This is correct you should find at the end the constants  @grey

Comment: But why we are supposing that equality? Can you share additional information?

Comment: @user577215664 Type `4^{n-1}` to get $4^{(n-1)}$ and `a_{n-1}` to get $a_{n-1}$

Answer (score 0):

It is worth noting that the generating function approach does not require such guessing.  Let $A(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ be the ordinary generating function.  Then the recurrence and initial conditions imply that
\begin{align}
A(z) &= a_0 z^0 + a_1 z^1 + a_2 z^2 + \sum_{n=3}^\infty \left(7a_{n-1} - 16a_{n-2} +12a_{n-3} + n4^n\right) z^n \\
&= -2 + 5z^2 + 7z \sum_{n=3}^\infty a_{n-1} z^{n-1} - 16z^2 \sum_{n=3}^\infty a_{n-2} z^{n-2} + 12z^3 \sum_{n=3}^\infty a_{n-3} z^{n-3} + \sum_{n=3}^\infty n (4z)^n \\
&= -2 + 5z^2 + 7z (A(z) - a_0 - a_1z) - 16 z^2 (A(z) - a_0) + 12 z^3 A(z) + \frac{(4z)^3(3-2(4z))}{(1-4z)^2} \\
&= -2 + 5z^2 + 7z (A(z) + 2) - 16 z^2 (A(z) + 2) + 12 z^3 A(z) + \frac{64z^3(3-8z)}{(1-4z)^2},
\end{align}
So
\begin{align}
A(z) &= \frac{-2 + 5z^2 + 14z - 32 z^2 + \frac{64z^3(3-8z)}{(1-4z)^2}}{1-7z+16z^2-12z^3} \\ &= \frac{-2+30z-171z^2+632z^3-944z^4}{(1-2 z)^2 (1-3 z) (1-4 z)^2} \\
&= \frac{-5/2}{1-2 z} + \frac{39/2}{(1-2 z)^2}+\frac{61}{1-3 z} - \frac{96}{1-4 z} + \frac{16}{(1-4 z)^2} \\
&= \frac{-5}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (2z)^n + \frac{39}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+1}{1}(2z)^n+61\sum_{n=0}^\infty (3z)^n - 96\sum_{n=0}^\infty (4z)^n + 16\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+1}{1}(4z)^n \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{-5}{2}\cdot 2^n + \frac{39}{2} (n+1)2^n + 61\cdot 3^n - 96\cdot 4^n + 16(n+1)4^n\right)z^n \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(17\cdot 2^n + \frac{39}{2} n2^n + 61\cdot 3^n - 80\cdot 4^n + 16n4^n\right)z^n,
\end{align}
which immediately implies that
$$a_n = 17\cdot 2^n + \frac{39}{2} n2^n + 61\cdot 3^n - 80\cdot 4^n + 16n4^n.$$

Comment: the issue is that it needs to be solved with the method i showed. but thanks for your contribution